# Running totals calculation by factor

Tags: r, cumsum

I would like to get running totals according to factors (Well_N), that's why I grouped data with

```
by_wells_sample <- group_by(sampledata, Well_N)
```

I would like to get running totals as new column in my dataframe, but as a result I get dataframe in the data frame. Any advice/guidance how to do it properly?

See [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dainiuxt/Runing-totals-R) with question details.

Comment: You mean you want a cumulative sum? check out `?cumsum`. Since you seem to use `dplyr`: it should be something like: `mutate(by_wells_sample, newcolumnname = cumsum(valuesToSumUp))`

Comment: Thanks for remarks. Actually, some of my listed code in Git repo works. The reason for my failure was that my data was unsorted according to dates. After I applied
`sampledata <- sampledata[order(as.Date(monthly$Date_m, format="%Y-%m-%d")),]`
everything went well.